# Android: ORDER BY in database query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Let's say I have these values in my database, column SCORE
{
70, 90, 100 , 110, 80
}
Why does when i use this code,

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(sqliteHelper.TABLE_SCORES, allColumns, null, null, null, null, sqliteHelper.SCORE + " DESC");
```

It was sorted like { 90,80,70,110,100 }

I think it sorts like that because 9>1?? How can I solve this?

Comment: what is datatype of column `score`??

Comment: Cast the column to a numeric type: `"CAST(" + sqliteHelper.SCORE + " AS INTEGER) DESC"`

Comment: Mike M. that solved the problem. Thanks!!